# Upload a file from JS Client to Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, paperclip

I've a rails backend, which manage pics using Paperclip.
There is a JS (Backbone/jQuery) client which present the datas and so on. We would like to let him upload files on the Backend.

Is there a way to interface the JS with PaperClip ?

Thx

Comment: Is PaperClip just a library for assisting with storing files attached to records? If so, then I'm unsure why your front end needs to specifically interact with PaperClip.  I figure it'd be just like most backbone apps - the front end can talk to the back end via AJAX, and your back-end should be handling persistence.

Comment: Paperclip also deal with pic size using imageMagick. But yes, we could directly upload the pic to the S3 from client. But it's not a good thing for other clients (such as mobile apps)